# Why does the for loop use a semicolon?

Tags: language-agnostic

In most C-derived languages (C, Java, Javascript, etc), the `for` loop is of the same basic syntax

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // code here
}
```

Why does this syntax contain semicolons, when semicolons are usually reserved for the end of the line? Also, why is there no semicolon after `i++`?

Comment: Semicolons are not reserved for the end of the line; that's just where they usually are, due to good style.

Comment: Its just a convention they came up with for a divider but sort of makes sense in that the 1st and 3rd parts are sort of like statements.

Comment: `for` loops are syntax sugar for scoped variable declarations and whatnot.

Comment: These are not "*most languages*", these are just the C-derived ones.  There are many, *many* more languages than just those descended from C.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/195642/why-are-semicolons-and-commas-interchanged-in-for-loops

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This pseudo-code:

```
for (A; B; C) {
    D;
}
```

can be internally converted to

```
{ // scope bracket
    A;
    while (B) {
        D;
        C;
    }
}
```

Comment: The early for loop was probably just syntactic sugar of those days.

Comment: Ah, but your expansion does have a semicolon after `C`.

Comment: @Robert Yes, it's not perfect, but I believe this is the etymology. There also *isn't* one after `B`. As Lee and Jesus said, it's syntactic sugar. It would be silly to have `for (A; B C;)`.

Comment: It's one of the most counter-intuitive language constructions I've ever seen, yet I've become used to it to a point where I actually like it. Yet I hate the creative versions of for some people write, with missing parts, combinations of commands and queries, weird increments, etc.

Comment: thanks, thinking of for loop syntax as shorthand for this helps put the syntax together a little better in my head.

Answer (score 2):

The semicolon is not for ending lines. It's for ending instructions. In most of those languages you can do:

```
int i;i = 0;
```

And it's legal. Look for any minified Javascript code. You'll see thousands of semicolons per line.

By the same principle, a for block takes three instructions. They are separated by semicolons so that the compiler or interpreter knows where each command starts and ends.

This is perfectly legal (though it results in an infinite loop):

```
for (;;) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel this can be answered sufficiently by examining how language parsers resolve the syntax. For example, a common depiction of a for loop is:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment-decrement) {
    /** statements **/
}
```

You can generalize that to:

```
for (expression; expression; expression) {
    /** statements **/
}
```

Note that the generalization is not entirely accurate, because the middle expression is typically reserved only for relational expressions, and the other two are either statements or statement lists. For example, in C and C++ you can have multiple statements in the initializer or increment-decrement regions by using the comma (,) operator.

It may help to note that statements are usually a collection of zero or more expressions, often separated by operators.

### Why does the for loop syntax use semicolons?

In many languages, a semicolon doesn't occur at the end of a line of code, it typically occurs at the **end of a statement.** A statement is a often defined as the smallest standalone executable element of a piece of code. A common type of statement is an expression statement, which is a statement composed of exactly one expression. This helps to explain why there is a semicolon at the end of each expression in the for loop construct, because it is consistent with how the language parser interprets statements.

### Why is there no semicolon at the end?

There is no semicolon at the end simply because that's how the language grammar is defined. The other components, as mentioned above, could be for consistency.

### What about languages that don't use semicolons as mentioned?

This is difficult to answer, but I think a probable reason is that it's consistent with how it has been done in the past. C was/is a very popular language, and many languages base their syntax on some variant of C including C++, C#, Objective-C, Java, Python, Perl, and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is no rational explanation for why this specific `for(;;){}` syntax was born. You should ask Kernighan or Ritchie about that.

Going back in the history of programming languages to the first '60s, the curly braces could have appeared in BCPL programming language, while the parantheses wrapping conditions where glorified by B (which only had a `while` statement, no `for`). C was modelled over B.

Since 1972, C has penetrated all sectors of computer engineering and subsequent languages where often modelled on C syntax (C++, Java, Javascript, C#, Scala, just to name a few) not to upset the habits of established programmers. This includes the `for(;;)` loop syntax and curly braces.

As a sidenote, there are many widespread languages not resorting to a C-style syntax, such as Python, whose `for` loop you may find more logic (obviuosly, this is a personal opionion), or Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The general form is:

```
for ( expression; expression; expression ) { ... }
```

The parser can easily recognize these expression because their syntax is identical to the sintax of "normal" expressions:

```
{
    expression;
    expression;
    ...
}
```

The last expression can easily be recognized because it ends with a ')'.
Furthermore, commas couldn't be used because they can be put inside single expressions:

```
for ( i=1,j=10; i<10,j>0; i++,j--) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` is a language keyword/instruction - not to be confused with calls to library functions.

keyword/instructions are part of the language; if, while, do, for, etc.  As such the compiler will need to generate assembly code (or instruction code of some kind) during compilation, interpretation.  When the `for` instruction was being developed in the c language (by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie), they would have had to choose the syntax of the for operation, and how the operation was going to break down into assembler

From:

```
for( start-condition ; end-condition ; step-control )
```

to something like this:

```
mov eax, $x
beginning:
cmp eax, 0x0A
jg end
inc eax
jmp beginning
end:
mov $x, eax
```

this syntax was then used in C++, and other languages followed suite.

in c the semicolon is a line/command terminator. in other language it is a line separator.  In the for loop it is a separator for the terms.

in c not all terms are required:

```
for(;;)
```

is valid code. and is equivalent to `while(1)` (pseudo: while(true))

in Pascal/modular2 the structure is different

```
for i:= start_value to end_value do
```